# How do I put these input elements on the center of the page, make the below divs align perfectly, and keep the prior span elements to the left?

Tags: css

I have three inputs with a span before and a div after, the last having an `i` element immediately after:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="recaptcha_form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="form_legend">Create Account</legend>
            <div class="form_field">
                <span class="validate_symbol">&#10007;</span>
                <input type="text" class="register_field" id="id_username">
                <div style = "display:none" class="error" aria-live="polite"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_field">
                <span class="validate_symbol">&#10007;</span>
                <input type="text" class="register_field"id="id_username">
                <div class="error" aria-live="polite"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_field">
                <span class="validate_symbol" >&#10007;</span>
                <input type="text" class="register_field"id="id_username">
                <i id="password_toggle">SHOW</i>
                <div class="error" ></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input{
  width: 200px;
}

/* Error messages below input */
.error{
  /* Same width as above input */
  width: 200px;
  /* Width of .validate_symbol */
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  background-color: #b30000;
  text-align: center;
}
.validate_symbol{
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: none;
}
/* SHOW/HIDE password element */
#password_toggle{
    margin-left: -45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Which results in:

[image]

I have also added CSS:

```
body{
  text-align: center;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Which results in:

[image]

The .error div still not being perfectly aligned with the above input and added "show" text causing misalignment of the password field.

I would like to center the input elements, while keeping the .validate_symbol elements immediately before on all screen sizes and perfectly align the .error divs with the above input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your code (simplifying the class names) and this was the result:

[image: Simple form with errors]

Here my code, I hope it helps! ‍

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create Account</legend>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="error">I am an error.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="error">I am an error.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="error">I am an error.</div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.container form fieldset {
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  border: none;
}

.container form fieldset legend {
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container form fieldset .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.container form fieldset .wrapper input {
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

.container form fieldset .wrapper .error {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.container form fieldset .wrapper:before {
  content: "X";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  left: 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist? What was the crucial change? Can you summarise? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65718226/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).